# Entity Framework Update Table with only keys

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I've got two keys, and want to update the foreign keys in a single query, without pulling it out  first(for efficiency reasons)

In other words, I'm wondering if there's any way to run the following query with entity

```sql
UPDATE User_Conversation
SET LastReadMessageId = @lastReadMessageId
WHERE Id = @userConversationId
AND UserId = @currentUserId -- for security
```

Comment: Viva ADO.Net. I really hate ORMs.

Comment: The more I use them, the less I like them :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use "Attach" function with State=Modified for fields that you want to update.

Check [here](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/dbcontext/modifying-data) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for this - it looks like the `attach` function needs an object though. This question is about avoiding pulling the object from the database before updating it, so for the purposes of this question, I don't have an object to call `attach` with

Comment: No dear, Attach function needs an empty object with just primary-key filled for tracking.

Comment: Oh! Thanks.. Then, I suppose I didn't include quite enough information here. I'd assumed any solution would allow an additional `where` to be added. Upvoted, but please see the updated query